# Plotar linhas de duas matrizes diferentes no R?

Tags: r, matriz, barplot

Eu tenho duas matrizes com mesmo número de linhas e diferentes número de colunas. Cada matriz é uma amostra, cada linha é um composto (1,2 e 3), e cada coluna é o número do resíduo. O valor na matriz são números de contatos que o ligante x faz com o resíduo y. Pois bem, eu gostaria de comparar a diferença de contato do composto 1 (2 e 3) entre as amostras.
O que eu tenho é:

```r
matrix1

structure(c(4L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 
4L, 8L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 14L, 6L, 
16L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 14L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 1L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(3L, 
24L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3"), c("84", "120", "123", 
"124", "126", "142", "150", "151", "152", "155", "157", "167", 
"168", "170", "82", "51", "78", "158", "74", "75", "76", "77", 
"90", "153"))) 

matrix2  

structure(c(2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 8L, 
0L, 1L, 16L, 23L, 2L, 14L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
4L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 15L, 0L, 7L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 
0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 
0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 2L), .Dim = c(3L, 27L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3"), c("82", "84", "75", "76", "77", "132", 
    "133", "138", "153", "154", "155", "156", "157", "158", "164", 
    "53", "167", "170", "51", "85", "87", "88", "89", "90", "152", 
    "168", "169")))
```

Eu gostaria de plotar gráfico de barras POR LIGANTE (ou seja, linha 1 da matrix 1 e linha 1 da matrix 2). Segue um exemplo para um ligante, para ficar mais ou menos assim (no caso abaixo é com três matrizes, no meu caso são duas):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero fazer três gráficos separados para cada ligante (1, 2 e 3). Alguém poderia me ajudar?